# Probability on accident

Tags: probability

There were four accidents in a town during a seven-day period. Would you be surprised if all four occurred on the same day? If each of the four occurred on a different day?

I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem. It looks like that it is somewhat related to Poisson distribution.

Comment: There are $7^4$ ways of distributing the accidents between the days. Are they equally probable? How many have all the accidents on the same day? On different days?

Comment: Probability of happening on same day $ = \frac{7}{7^4}$. And the probability of happening on different days $ = \frac{7*6*5*4}{7^4}$. Please check if it is correct

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised.  For one thing, they could all be related, for example a particular weather condition on that day.  Apart from that, it isn't that unlikely, even if the accidents were totally independent.   All on the same day is about one in 2500 - things have to happen in the world that are less likely - ok so you might check if there WAS a connection between them I suppose - it's not 1 in 2500, it's the one you got 1/7^3

Comment: I agree with your calculations.  I would say case 1 - cursory check that there was not a common cause.  Case 2 : check it wasn't a 1 a day lunatic causing the problem

Comment: @Henry I wanted to ask if the op has calculated the correct probability of accidents occurring on different days. Wouldnt it be ${7}\choose{4}$ in the numerator?

Comment: @Damn1o1 - no, sv_jan5 was correct in the comment with $7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4$, making the probability about $0.349854$ and so not an extreme result

Answer (score 2):

The probabilities are:

- all the same day different days $\frac{7}{7^4}= \approx 0.00292$ as you say in a comment  - this might be described as surprising if they are unconnected (perhaps people only drive through the village on a particular day when the by-pass was closed)
- all different days $\frac{7\times 6 \times 5\times 4}{7^4} \approx 0.34985$ as you say in a comment - this is not particularly surprising
- on two days $\frac{7 \times 6\times 4 + 7\times 6 \times 3}{7^4}\approx 0.12245$ since you can either have three on one day and one another or two on each of two days
- on three days $\frac{7 \times 6\times 5 \times 6}{7^4}\approx 0.52478$

and, as a check, these probabilities add up to $1$

Comment: I am not getting numerator of all different days. Can you explain it to me ? Also tell me 7 choose 4 will also choose days with gap in it . So are we talking about consecutive days?

Comment: @Damn1o1 - For different days: (a) the first accident on the list can be any of 7 days, the second any of the other 6, the third any of the the other 5, and the fourth any of the other 4, then multiply; or (b) the accidents can be spread across the days ${7 \choose 4}$ ways but can be ordered $4!$ ways within the selected days, then multiply.  Bot approaches give the same result

Comment: I got that part. And in your third case(on two days), I am having $\frac{7 \times 6\times 3}{7^4}$ because there are three possibilities $(1,3),(3,1),(2,2)$. The first possibility implies 1 accident on one day and 3 accidents on another day. How did you get  $\frac{7 \times 6 \times 4}{7^4}$ ?

Comment: @Damn1o1 - $7 \times 6 \times 3$ is just the $(2,2)$ cases. $7 \times 6 \times 4$ is for the $(3,1)$ cases with $7$ possibilities for the three, $6$ other possibilities for the one and $4$ possible ways of choosing which three out of four

Comment: You went this far so help me a little more please tell me how did we get $3$ in $(2,2)$ case. The way I am thinking is that $2$ accidents can happen in $7$ days making it$ 7$ ways and other$ 2$ can happen in any other 6 days. That makes $7\times 6$ .

Comment: @Damn1o1 - in the $(2,2)$ case a particular accident can happen on any of $7$ days and the other day with accidents can be any of the other $6$ days, and the accident which happens on the same day as the first particular accident can be any of the other $3$ accident